# Can I automate vm instance setup with Multipass?

Tags: ubuntu-18.04, multipass

I'm using [multipass](https://multipass.run/) to setup an Ubuntu virtual machine image. I'd like to make the installation of apt packages repeatable. Is it possible to script this somehow?

Comment: Yes it possible using `multipass exec …`

Answer (score 2):

You could create a cloud-config file and add it via --cloud-init option when launching a fresh VM. Cloud init lets you provision a VM on almost any cloud provider, it's a very versatile tool. That way you can add any package you want, create news users, run bash commands etc. .
More on cloud-config files [here](https://cloudinit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/examples.html).

You then run a cloud-config file with:

```
multipass launch -n your_vm_name --cloud-init path/to/cloudconfig/file.yaml
```